# How to update a array value in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I want to update a array value but i am not sure about the proper method to do it ,so for i tried following method but didnt worked for me.

My model,
    The children field in my model

```
   childrens: {
       type: Array,
       default: ''
  }
```

My query,

```
   Employeehierarchy.update({ _id: employeeparent._id} ,{ $set: {"$push": { "childrens": employee._id }} })
   .exec(function (err, managerparent) {});
```

Can anyone please provide me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't use both **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** and **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)** in the same update expression as nested operators.

The correct syntax for using the [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#update-operators) follows:

```
{
   <operator1>: { <field1>: <value1>, ... },
   <operator2>: { <field2>: <value2>, ... },
   ...
}
```

where `<operator1>, <operator2>` can be from any of the update operators list specified [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#fields).

For adding a new element to the array, a single **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)** operator will suffice e.g. you can use the **[`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)** update method to return the modified document as

```
Employeehierarchy.findByIdAndUpdate(employeeparent._id,
    { "$push": { "childrens": employee._id } },
    { "new": true, "upsert": true },
    function (err, managerparent) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(managerparent);
    }
);
```

Using your original **[`update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)** method, the syntax is

```
Employeehierarchy.update(
   { "_id": employeeparent._id},
   { "$push": { "childrens": employee._id } },
   function (err, raw) {
       if (err) return handleError(err);
       console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
   }
);
```

in which the callback function receives the arguments `(err, raw)` where

- `err` is the error if any occurred
- `raw` is the full response from Mongo

Since you want to check the modified document, I'd suggest you use the **[`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)** function since the **[`update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)** method won't give you the modified document, just the full write result from mongo.

---

If you want to update a field in the document and add an element to an array at the same time then you can do

```
Employeehierarchy.findByIdAndUpdate(employeeparent._id,
    { 
        "$set": { "name": "foo" },
        "$push": { "childrens": employee._id } 
    } 
    { "new": true, "upsert": true },
    function (err, managerparent) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(managerparent);
    }
);
```

The above will update the `name` field to "foo" and add the employee id to the `childrens` array.

Comment: If i test for manager print  console.log(managerparent+'kk') i am getting error as  uncaughtException: managerparent is not defined

Comment: Thsnks chridam it wrkd.

Comment: still i have one more question for you :),if you are OK.

Comment: Hi chridam,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506447/how-to-update-records-on-continues-hierarchy-in-momgoose

Answer (score 3):

can follow this

if `childrens` contains string values then model can be like:

```
childrens: [{
    type : String
}]
```

if `childrens` contains ObjectId values of another collection `_id` and want populate then model can be like:

```
childrens: [{
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'refModelName'
}]
```

no need to use `$set` just use `$push` to insert value in `childrens` array. so  query can be like:

```
Employeehierarchy.update(
   { _id: employeeparent._id},
   {"$push": { "childrens": employee._id } }
 ).exec(function (err, managerparent) {
    //
 });
```

Comment: I model is declared so it may become as array of objects?Which i dont want

Comment: not array of object will be array that will contains ids (as string for first process and for second process as a ObjectId)  @nlr_p

Answer (score 3):

This will help I guess

```
Employeehierarchy.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id:employeeparent._id },
  { $set: { "childrens": employee._id }}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose v8 the syntax is a little bit cleaner and more readable:

```
const body = request.body;

await JourneyModel.updateOne({
    "days._id": body._id 
   },{
      $set: {
        'days.$.driverName': body.driverName,
        'days.$.driverPhone': body.driverPhone,
        'days.$.driverNeeded': false,
        'days.$.driverInfoUpdatedBy': new mongo.ObjectId(user._id).toString(),
        'days.$.lastModifiedAt': new Date().toISOString(),
      }
})
```