# How to update records on continues Hierarchy in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a record in such a way like below

1)

```
{
 "name":"A",
 "parents":[ADMIN],
 "childrens":[B,C,D]    
  }
```

2)

```
 {
 "name":"B",
 "parents":[A],
 "childrens":[D,K,L]    
  }
```

3)

```
{
 "name":"C",
 "parents":[B],
 "childrens":[K,L]    
  }
```

4)

```
{
 "name":"D",
 "parents":[C],
 "childrens":[L]    
  }
```

Here if a add a new record 'E' and will make 'C'  as parent ,then the logic is the record 'E' should be added as child to the parent of 'C'i.e for 'B' and at the same time 'E' should also be added to parent of 'B'.This logic is quite confusing when i start to write code and complex too but i achieved up to some extent that i can make 'E' as a child of 'C' and also the parent of 'C' but not further.
My Code:

```
function (callback) {
  var item = {'employee' : employee.manager };
  Employeehierarchy.find(item).exec(function (err, employeeparent) {
      if (employeeparent && employeeparent.length > 0) {
        Employeehierarchy.update(
       { _id: employeeparent[0]._id},
       {"$push": { "childrens": employee._id } }
     ).exec(function (err, managerparent) {
     });
      callback(err,employeeparent);
      } else{
        callback(err,employeeparent);
      }
    }
  });
},
//Finding the parent record of the manager in hierarchy
function (employeeparent, callback) {
  var item = {'employee' : employeeparent[0].parents };
  Employeehierarchy.find(item).exec(function (err, managerparent) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) });
    } else {
      if (managerparent && managerparent.length > 0) {console.log(managerparent+'managerparent')
        Employeehierarchy.update(
       { _id: managerparent[0]._id},
       {"$push": { "childrens": employee._id } }
     ).exec(function (err, managerparent) {
     });
          callback(err,managerparent);
      } else{
          callback(err,managerparent);
      }
    }
  });
}else {
  callback();
}
```