# Can't seem to update nested values in imported database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I import to mongodb a database, that looks like this:

```
{
    other values,
    "addresses" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 
            "createdAt" : 
            "likes" : 
            "type" : 
            "route" : 
            "country" : 
            "administrative_area_level_1" : 
            "administrative_area_level_2" : 
            "locality" : 
            "postal_code" : 
            "street_number" : 
        }
    ],
    other values
}
```

I want to add a new property to the database and thus create this schema:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    addresses: [{
        route: String,
        coordinates:[{
            coordsSet: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            lat: String,
            lon: String
        }]
    }],
    name: String,     
});
```

And while I can find the record by ID for example I am unable to set coordinates to the new record after I call google API. I do it this way:

```
   baza.findOneAndUpdate({ "addresses._id": response.id }, {$set: {"addresses.coordinates[0].lat": response.lat}}).then((update) =>{
            res.send(update);
        })
```

But I am unable to do that. res.send shows that I created `"coordinates": []`, however I cannot set it.

I dont have this problem when I want to add those new properties outside the adresses object, so I suppose I am failing with nesting some information. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wrap your `$set` in quotation marks like so, `"$set"`. Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501939/how-to-update-a-array-value-in-mongoose#41502103) question

Comment: There is no change in behaviour whatsoever

Comment: Can you attempt to use `findByIdAndUpdate` and see if there is any difference in behaviour?

Comment: Just tried that, also no change in behaviour. I just dont understand why it works outside of addresses but not inside of them

Comment: Can you supply what `other_values` are presented as in Mongo? So just copy the structure and omit any values that are sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
baza.findOneAndUpdate({ "addresses._id": response.id }, {$set:{"addresses.coordinates[0].lat": response.lat}}, { new : true }).then((update) =>{
            res.send(update);
        })
```

The third param '{ new : true }' means return the modified document.

Comment: I have no problem with returning modified document, because it's not getting modified, thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Google API returns lat long in float, not String

And you have specified String in the schema, That may be the reason the it is not getting stored. mongoose won't allow any data to be stored if it is not in the specified format. and They don't give in error as well.

Try

```
 baza.findOneAndUpdate({ "addresses._id": response.id }, {$set: {"addresses.coordinates[0].lat": response.lat.toString()}}).then((update) =>{
            res.send(update);
        })
```

If this does not work can you post the whole schema? With all child schemas.

**Edit :-** Do you already have a 0th element in coordinates key in the document? If you don't have any then $set won't work. You will have to use

```
$push : { coordinates : { lat :   response.lat.toString() }}
```

**Edit** This finally did the trick

as addresses itself is an array you have to push with $ operator or index

```
$push : { "addresses.$.coordinates" : { lat : response.lat }}
```

Comment: I tried it, no change in behaviour. Also mongoose didnt have problem with setting the lat lon as string when I did it outside of the adresses object. I will try one more solution proposed above and if it doesnt work ill post whole schema but thats pretty much it what you already see. Unless I have to copy ALL properties to schema in order to make it work

Comment: I didnt have any elements before, so I used $push. Tried with quotes and without quotes, sadly, it still doesnt make it work. I will post my whole Schema in 1 minute

Comment: Made it work. I used `{$set: {addresses: {coordinates: {lat:response.lat }} }}}`  so switched push with set after all

Comment: Well That's strange, But whatever works for you.

Although this would set lattitude of every object in the entire array.

Comment: Well, youre right it actually overwritten the rest of the address. So it still doesnt work after all, no idea why push wont work at this point

Comment: okay wait, addresses itself is an array.. Try this

$push : { "addresses.$.coordinates" : { lat :   response.lat }}

Comment: Both push and set works now, instead of dollar sign i simply used 0 for now, because all arrays are single element for now. Thank you