# Change in the mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
const appliedBySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
    status: { type: String, default: "Pending" }
});

const positionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    job_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:"ad"},
    postedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:"user" },
    positionName: String,
    reqExp: String,
    appliedBy: [appliedBySchema],
    dept:{type:String , default: false},
    mainRole:{type: String, default: false},
    genderStrictly:{type: String, default:false},
    ageStrictly:{type: String, default:false}
    });
```

I want to change the status in `appliedBySchema`, please tell me the mongo query that I have to write to update the status. The model of `positionSchema` present but the model of `appliedBySchema` does not exist.

Comment: `The model of positionSchema present but the model of appliedBySchema does not exist.` What is means ?

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr I think what he's trying to say is that he has run `mongoose.model()` on the position schema but not on the `appliedBySchema`]

Comment: Correct, @cr05s19xx.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to update the `appliedBySchema`, which is an array of objects inside a document, you have various options (which a quick Google search will prove useful for). But off the top of my head, you can try the following

```
const Position = mongoose.model('positions', positionSchema);
const toUpdate = await Position.findById(idToUse, 'appliedBy');

const appliedBy = toUpdate.appliedBy || [];   // I now have access to all the applied by data
toUpdate.appliedBy = appliedBy.map(entity => {
    // Make manipulations on the entity
    return entity;
});

await appliedBy.save();
```

This is just to get it running. But there are **far better options out there**, such as:

- [How to update an array value in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501939/how-to-update-a-array-value-in-mongoose)
- [Mongoose update of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691224/mongoose-update-values-in-array-of-objects/15691950)